# ST_DistanceSphere can't deal with the prime meridian?

Tags: postgis

I have a table of weather stations, and I wanted to find stations near London. I ran this query:

```
select id, name, location, ST_DistanceSphere(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.51 -0.12)')) as dist from stations order by dist;
```

The query seems to work fine, up until the 13th row:

```
id          name        location                    dist
USC00500252 AMCHITKA    POINT (51.3833 179.2833)    94097.52204081
```

This is a weather station in the Aleutians. Needless to say, it is quite a lot more than 94km from London (and I expect the weather there is not especially similar to London's). How can I get `ST_DistanceSphere` to account for longitude correctly?

NB: I've tried adding the SRID: `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.51 -0.12)', 4326)`. This doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostGIS, the coordinates must be expressed as Longitude first, then Latitude. You have swapped them

Comment: ‍♂️ Well, now I feel silly. Thanks.